# What do the 4 icons under the player name mean at the bottom of their callsign?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the four slots under emblem and badges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35026/what-are-the-four-slots-under-emblem-and-badges)

When looking at other players in the MW3 multiplayer lobby, I noticed that some players have icons under their name.  I just have 4 empty holes.

What do these icons mean and how are they earned?